# SageMaker ValidationException : Value '[]' at 'subnetIds' failed to satisfy constraint

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

---

### 1 validation error detected
Value '[]' at 'subnetIds' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1

I want to make Sagemaker studio Domain in Ohio region, but I got ↑ error.
I also confirmed that vpc existed (no default) and one subnet existed.

How can I fix the error? Please share your knowledge.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, i cant seem to find a solution on the internet

Answer (score 8):

On the setup SageMaker Domain screen, if you've been trying with the "Quick Setup" instead try using the "Standard Setup". That got me past this issue.